# Specific day of current month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have problem with return of specific day of current month and year. I need for example 15th day. Until now I used in FB/IB existing function:

```
IB_EncodeDate(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Date),EXTRACT(Month FROM Current_Date),15)
```

Does it exist a simply way to convert this for MSSQL database?

edit. I need output in OLE format (41,348 by example) to compare date with another date. I compare date from database with 15th day of current month.

Comment: I can't find reference to the IB_EncodeDate function anywhere online. Can you give an example showing the output of the function?

Comment: @Nate: IB stands for InterBase, FB to Firebird accordingly.

Comment: Is the output of the function character or date typed?

Comment: ib_encodeDate is UDF (user defined fucntion) and I don't know how is it works.
Output of this function is by example 41,338. Date in OLE format (I gues)

Comment: Why would you change the requirement 5 days later? And if your "date" is stored as a float, could you specify that in the question, and give a few sample values and indicate what date they should resolve to?

Answer (score 8):

For the 15th day of current month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 14, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
```

To get the silly OLE representation based on this "magic" date, 1899-12-30:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, DATEADD(DAY, 14, 
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)));
```

Answer (on March 11th, when I updated this answer for the changed requirement):

```
-----
41348
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you have a date, and want to return the 15th day of the same month?. Well, assuming SQL Server 2008, you could do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)+'15',112)
```

For Previous versions of SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)+'15',112)
```

Comment: Thanks, I use:
'cast(CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)+'15') as float)' 
and it looks like working right.

Comment: Is here a way, how can I this use for actual date + 7? By example, if today is 5.3, so I need 12.3.

Comment: @Sk1X1 I'm lost at what is it that you really want. Why do you want to cast the date as `FLOAT`?, what do you mean with your last comment?, do you want to add 7 days to a date?, so use `DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE())`, no need to cast it to float an add 7

Comment: I need date in float to compare it with another date.
Thanks, on this function I forgot. 
I'm new in SQL and I convert SQL scripts from Firebird to MSSQL.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Ok, whatever works for you. I still don't know why you need to convert a date to a float to compare it to another **date**.

Comment: All dates in my databases are saved as float.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Ok then. So, a word of advice, in the future, store dates as a date datatype on your database

Comment: Thanks for advice. This is company database and unfortunately I have to work with this what I get.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Oy vey. Dates as floats! Do you store salary as strings and names in varbinary?

Comment: my username is 0x737761736865636B

Comment: @Sk1X1 is this your company? If so you have to get them to change that. There is NO I repeat NO reason to store date/datetimes as a float. One more time NO reason to store Dates as float. None. Ever.

Comment: Float is probably among the worst choices to use for a date field since it's an **approximate** data type.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a quick answer.

```
declare @OLEDate int 
declare @currentDate as datetime
set @currentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 14, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
set @OLEDate = convert(float, @currentdate) 
-- PRINT @OLEDate
```

based on Aaron Bertrand's answer and your need for the integer conversion

Answer (score 1):

To get 10th day of current day

```
declare @cur_month int,@cur_yr int,@tenth_dt date
    set @cur_month=month(getdate())
    set @cur_yr=YEAR(getdate())
    set @tenth_dt=convert(date,'10/'+convert(varchar(5),@cur_month)+'/'+convert(varchar(5),@cur_yr),103)
    select @tenth_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

`Current_Date` in SQL Server would be `getdate()`.

To get the 15th day in OLE Automation format, try:

```
select datediff(day, '18991230', dateadd(day, -day(getdate()) + 15, getdate()))
```

Comment: Datename? Be very careful. Regional / language settings might not treat you well here.

Comment: In what way? It's only there to facilitate a cast to datetime, i.e. it's not used in two different contexts. This could have used `month()`, but I don't think this would break.

Comment: Why would you rely on a regional date string? How do you know how the OP (or any future reader) will use it?

Comment: After having to do this myself today, I've updated my answer.

Comment: But this has a time component. If it is being used as an endpoint in a range query, for example, it won't capture the whole day unless you happen to run this code precisely at midnight.

Comment: don't `Geez` me, please. Accuracy is important. The question is clear, they need to compare a ***DATE***, not a specific point in time. And for this conversion, it is very expensive to convert to string, and [you should never use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). These details may not be important to you, but they are important to the OP and other readers.

Comment: Actually, he put in an update to ask for the date in a specific format, so I've updated for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you after `Day` or `Date`. This gives both dayOfWeek and specificDate for any culture

```
declare @myDay int = 15

select convert(date,myday) specificDate, datename(dw,myday) dayOfWeek
from (
   select convert(varchar(6),getdate(),112) + convert(varchar, @myDay) myday
) x
```

**[Fiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9964)**

```
| SPECIFICDATE | DAYOFWEEK |
----------------------------
|   2013-02-15 |    Friday |
```

Comment: Please don't use [date shorthands like `dw`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) or [`convert(varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). These are bad practices to use yourself, never mind suggesting to other users...

Answer (score 0):

A bit more straightforward approach:

```sql
CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-15') AS DateTime)
```

Comment: Why do you find this more straightforward than the existing answers?